# Can a real number $x \in (0,1)$ have more than different 2 binary expansions?

Tags: binary

I know that a real number $x \in (0,1)$ can have 2 different binary expansion. *e.g 0.1 = 0.011111...*. But is there any real number for which there are more than 2 different binary expansions?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Every terminating binary expansion has exactly one companion with an infinite string of 1's.  Every other number has a unique binary expansion.  In fact, you can define the real numbers by these two properties.  A similar approach in the context of decimals was already developed in the 16th century by [Simon Stevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin).  The first record we have of a mathematician aware of the non-uniqueness of decimal representation seems to be in Euler.